# Python: Implementing an Equation

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, dynamic-programming

I am  trying to implement the following equation on python:

[image: 2 huge equations]

This is my code:

```
dumm = np.zeros((len(l)))
forwardmatrix = np.zeros((len(xhm), len(f)))

for i in range(0, len(xhm)):
    for j in range(0, len(f)):
        if (i==0):
            forwardmatrix[i][j]=np.log(f[j])+xhm[i][j]
        else:
            for k in range (0, len(l)):
                dumm[k]=forwardmatrix[i-1][k]+np.log(l[j][k])
            forwardmatrix[i][j]=logsumexp(dumm)+xhm[i][j]
```

So everything works (almost) well, the problem is that it only updates with correct values only the first column of each row, the rest of the values are updated to -INF.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: What are `l` and `xhm` initialized to? It might be the cause of the problem. Can you please add the initialization to the top of your code block?